# Type '{ contactData: Props[] | null; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am doing a simple props drilling using typeScript. I want to pass the array from my useState  hook to the  component. But I couldn't pass the props as it's mentioned in the warning dialogue.

```
Type '{ contactData: Props[] | null; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props[]'.   Property 'contactData' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props[]'
```

I am wondering is there any type definition error or any props passing error. **please anyone pick me up from the sea.**
Here is the code:

```
import {useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";


interface Props {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

function App() {
  const [contactData, setContactData] = useState< Props[] | null>(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello from MARS</h1>
      <div className="container">
        <div>
          <TableData contactData={contactData}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

const TableData = ({contactData}: Props[]) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {!contactData && <p>No data to show!!</p>}
      {contactData.map((item: Props, index: number) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h2>Name: {item.name}</h2>
          <h3>Email: {item.email}</h3>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I pass the props to the components with compliant with typescript definition?

Answer (score 1):

I think type of TableData props is not correct

this :

```
({contactData}: Props[])
```

must be changed to :

```
({contactData}: {contactData:Props[]})
```

Comment: Thank you @Ali Sattarzadeh . I have got the point. 

Answer (score 1):

The first situation we need to deal with is the typing of `contactData`. You typed it as `Props[] | null`. But you are not dealing correctly with the possibility of `contactData` being `null` anywhere in your code. If `TableData` should also possibly accept `null` values, you need to add some sort of conditional to not execute the `map` because you can't call `map` on `null`.

To make it simple, I removed the `null` type and set the default value to be an empty array.

```
const [contactData, setContactData] = useState<Props[]>([]);
```

The props of `TableData` now need the following type.

```
const TableData = ({ contactData }: { contactData: Props[] }) => {
  /* ... */
}
```

The type describes an object which has a `contactData` property containing a `Props` array.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwK4GcCmBlGBDGa4C+cAZlBCHAERRrYDGMlA3ALABQoksVAdAPQBBMGB50UKZu07R4AJVoMSZCtQWN2GjgDs8UYvXwAFMmBSJ2cOFuwg0ALjgoYUYFoDmrNpbQhswADYOTi7ungSaxEhaDMAQWnBCYAAUAJTmXnB0cU5wANpZOvQwACK42AA0jmgwAMJxOAylOAC6cAC8cKiYOHgAPMYQprnNAHxJwymeFnA0MEhQ8UnTlr0AJsAAbpn+2OIAcjZobZSJlCPLlnC9ABYAjCMAEmj+-hBK5HAAsgKyGL18d3OGUuV3WWzoO32h2OBRwrjQUDOFxBa02QJBGKuABVsAAjfxoJrYTL1IpEtoIWFksoEPjozFXPhg+koploi7-ZnTSbscJsdhoAAeXHgqzQ+iQ-ngiSmbAKORx+MJZXacCSlNJjRpDgQJMKWpwDgGQ1aBDSbRG6Uss3miw5XOBlwQAEIqQbiQAyD1XMAjPZvVYqmBvFDXCAAd2dzv+vr5mI1+pKZR4vmSSWAeBARpMKEqrjFgocWiQIFxCPNlqWjpRYLgAGs0ABPCn5oUEFkMm4AJj9hx1GZ8PGstgI-2uPeRGJuAGYRgBRXwBfuZng+Pz+UcA2eTlZsjYdywpFJxy6c9kZHlsAhMIA)

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Tobias S.  I didn't handle the null value properly. It's a good convention to initialize the array as null. So I needed to pass condition that I didn't.  Your solution has worked. 